# Member function template argument default value

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, default-arguments

The following bit of code compiles in GCC 4.5.3 but does not compile in VS 2008 and 2010. Is this due to a VS compiler bug or does the standard forbid giving default function template argument values?

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct Bar
{
    enum Group{ A , B , C };
};

struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    static void getSome( typename T::Group = T::A );
};

template<typename T>
void Foo::getSome( typename T::Group )
{
};

int main()
{
    Foo::getSome<Bar>();            // Does not compile in VS 2008 & 2010 (compiles in gcc 4.5.3)
    Foo::getSome<Bar>( Bar::C );    // Compiles in VS 2008 and gcc 4.5.3
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error message

```
prog.cpp(11) : error C2589: '::' : illegal token on right side of '::'
prog.cpp(11) : error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a MSVC bug.

The bug is in the handling of template functions with default parameters, as you probably guessed.

Their workaround is to supply all function parameters.  *(yuck)*

Acknowledged [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/583081/).

Comment: Another lame alternative is to just provide the method with default parameter as an overload of the templated method, i.e. supply an additional `getSome()` which will just call `getSome(T::A)`. That also works with MSVC.

Answer (score 3):

I think `g++` is adhering to the standard when it compiles your snippet.

The following extract should be the reference to the right part of the standard (section 14.1.9):

> A default template-argument is a template-argument (14.3) specified
>   after = in a template-parameter. A default template-argument may be
>   specified for any kind of template-parameter (type, non-type,
>   template) that is not a template parameter pack (14.5.3). A default
>   template-argument may be specified in a template declaration. A
>   default template-argument shall not be specified in the
>   template-parameter-lists of the definition of a member of a class
>   template that appears outside of the member’s class. A default
>   template-argument shall not be specified in a friend class template
>   declaration. If a friend function template declaration specifies a
>   default template-argument, that declaration shall be a definition and
>   shall be the only declaration of the function template in the
>   translation unit.